# CIF file for Methyl Acrylate

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, cif

Methyl Acrylate has linear formula, molecular weight, density, and boiling point are C_4H_6O_2, 0.0861 kg/mol, 950 kg/m³, and 353 K respectively. I want to know the atomic positions for Methyl Acrylate. Does anyone know from where can I get it?

Comment: Chances for a .cif about the pure compound are low because of the low melting point (Wikipedia reports $\pu{-74 ^\circ{}C}$, [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_acrylate)) -- which is much more important to establish a model to describe a crystal structure in a .cif, than a boiling point of a compound. And 2), though XRD (especially on compounds of light organic) molecules *can* benefit from recording data at lowered sample temperature, there are not many groups crystallizing at these conditions and transfer the sample to the the machine maintaining the low temp.

Comment: It tends to polymerize (keyword super glue), so you would need someone to crystallize it right in a capillary already mounted on the diffractometer by a stream of nitrogen gas (possible, though not a routine  technique).

Answer (score 2):

See [ChemSpider](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.7022.html) and click on 3D, which will allow you to get the structure. And it is available within the Cambridge Database within e.g. entry [TORTUQ](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=TORTUQ&DatabaseToSearch=Published).

Comment: There is a bemol with TORTUQ: not only the molecules of methyl acrylate are present, so the intermolecular interactions and packing leading to the conformation the model displays *can* be a different one vs. *pure* methyl acrylate.  It still were worth to complement the query e.g. in the [COD](http://crystallography.net/cod/index.php).  And chemspider claims there are about 10k of entries from the CSD file ([reference](https://www.chemspider.com/DataSources.aspx)) - this is very little of the set with more than a million entries. Perhaps it is computed by a force field?

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no crystal structure of methyl acrylate alone. The TORTUQ entry at least has a well-resolved structure for it. Better something than nothing. The crystal structure is definitely a crystal structure, see the corresponding paper in Cryst. Growth Des., https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cg800658t

Comment: Thanks. If they start to polymerize (for example as a linear chain), how it's structure look like? @MSwart

Comment: Don't know, please check the CCDC database for a possible structure